# Connect cell phone to Linux

Tags: linux, mobile-phone, connector

when connecting a (an older) cell phone to a Linux computer, do I need software for each phone, or do they use a standard protocol?

I have an LG KP100, which is a cheap, old LG cell phone, and it uses a proprietary connector.
At least I think it is proprietary, as I haven't found a proper designation for that port.

Now, I'd like to connect that phone to my computer, and move some data back and forth. Obviously, I need a data cable for that, but what software should I use when connecting it to Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this works, I have never used ubuntu, still trying to help you. This is what it was suggested in another forum

Try wammu. It's in the repos.

> Code:
>
> sudo apt-get install wammu

to install it.

Edit: I ended up here http://www.bitpim.org/ please look here too http://www.verizon.com

And just to inform you that for Nokia phones there is a Nokia PC suite for Ubuntu

Comment: What? A Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu? Where? I need that!

Comment: I think it's called gnokii, but I'm not sure it's maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying BitPim at http://www.bitpim.org but it does not appear that your phone is listed there.  If you can connect it to the computer, it might be worth a shot.

I am on Ubuntu and can download this from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: I'll have a look on it and report back.

Answer (score 1):

All the phones I connected to ubuntu up to now worked without installing anything. I just pluged them in the USB, Ubuntu mounted them and they worked without problem. Most of them were rather old and simple. I'm sure I connected several phones from Sony-Ericsson and Motorola but not sure if I tried a LG. Anyways if your phone has some kind of memory card, at least the memory card will probably be identified and work even if the phone does not work and you can transfer from the phone to the memory card and back.

Comment: do you happen to know the kmods?

Comment: tbh... I'm not 100% sure of what `kmods` means as english is not my usual language but I suppose it's the data cable. I have no idea because the cell phones were not mine (I only use mine as a phone so I never connect it...) but from my teens sons and who knows where are the phones now... not speaking of the cables as I think they can't use a phone more than a few months without destroying it, exchange it or sell it! I'm not even sure the cables were from the right phones... lol the only thing I know is that they couldn't do it on windows without the software so they tried on my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using bitpim then there are some workarounds that may help get it working under Linux (both Ubuntu and Fedora).

1 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=145946&page=12

- This fix shows how to get the fedora built bitpim rpm on ubuntu. There are some broken/different shared library links in /usr/lib and /usr that need to be created manually to get bitpim working.

2 http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=84875

- This fix shows how to disable the prelinks tool from stripping out a "zip file" that is part of the bitpim executable. I encountered this problem on Fedora 14, not sure if it's still the case but it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have  Ubuntu 12.10 o 12.04 just update version of GVFS. 
Follow the next steps:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`